# addEventListener works incorrectly

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, event-listener

addSessionTimeBtn is supposed to increase the time value that is displayed on the screen. It works great when i use function without arguments as an event handler but when changeTime function is used value increases by 1 and then event listener starts to ignore clicking. What i'm doing wrong?

```
addSessionTimeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    changeTime(sessionMinutes, sessionSeconds, '+', 'Session')
})

reduceSessionTimeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    changeTime(sessionMinutes, sessionSeconds, '-', 'Session')
})

function changeTime(minutes, seconds, operation, period) {
    if (period === 'Session') {
        timerName.innerHTML = 'Session time';
    } else {
        timerName.innerHTML = 'Break time';
    }
    if (operation === '+') {
        seconds += 1;
        if (seconds > 59) {
            seconds = 0;
            minutes += 1;
        }
    } else {
        seconds -= 1;
        if (minutes > 0 && seconds < 0) {
            minutes -= 1;
            seconds = 59;
        } else if (minutes === 0 && seconds < 1) {
            seconds = 0;
        }
    }
    timer.innerHTML = `${timeLength(minutes)}:${timeLength(seconds)}`
}
```

Comment: changeTime takes 4 arguments you can't pass it directly to addEventLisener, since it would receive only the parameter `event`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing integers as arguments to your function, so as they are primitive values, they are passed by value, and the original variable you seem to target is not mutated (you can't have pointers to integer in js), and your timer is always reset to zero.

You could store your `sessionMinutes` and `sessionSeconds` in an object and pass that object, the object being passed as a reference, it will be mutated.

```js
const timer = document.getElementById("timer");
const timerName = document.getElementById("timername");

const session = {
  minutes: 0,
  seconds: 0
}

function changeTime(session, operation, period) {
  if (period === 'Session') {
    timerName.innerHTML = 'Session time';
  } else {
    timerName.innerHTML = 'Break time';
  }
  if (operation === '+') {
    session.seconds += 1;
    if (session.seconds > 59) {
      session.seconds = 0;
      session.minutes += 1;
    }
  } else {
    session.seconds -= 1;
    if (session.minutes > 0 && session.seconds < 0) {
      session.minutes -= 1;
      session.seconds = 59;
    } else if (session.minutes === 0 && session.seconds < 1) {
      session.seconds = 0;
    }
  }
  timer.innerHTML = `${session.minutes}:${session.seconds}`; // I don't know what timeLength does so I removed it just to illustrate, it doesn't change the point.
}

document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener('click', function() {
  changeTime(session, '+', 'Session')
});

document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener('click', function() {
  changeTime(session, '-', 'Session')
});
```

```html
<button id="plus">
+
</button>

<button id="minus">
-
</button>

<p id="timername">
Session
</p>
<p id="timer">
0:0
</p>
```